# Cannot load native library libLiteCore.dylib on M1

Tags: kotlin, gradle, jvm, apple-m1, couchbase-lite

I'm trying to build a JVM application (mostly Kotlin) on my M1 MacBook that uses CouchbaseLite.
I have this in my build.gradle file:

`implementation "com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-java:3.0.0-beta02"`
(also tried it with a non-beta version 2.8.4)

Gradle sync + build is fine but everytime I run the up and try to create a database

`db = Database(LOCAL_DB_NAME, config)`
I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load native library libLiteCore.dylib @/Users/ale/Projects/server/CouchbaseLiteTemp/5e3b1711cace9de693b3e1e0bea0f2f8/libLiteCore.dylib for Mac OS X/aarch64
    at com.couchbase.lite.internal.NativeLibrary.load(NativeLibrary.java:113)
    at com.couchbase.lite.internal.CouchbaseLiteInternal.init(CouchbaseLiteInternal.java:80)
    at com.couchbase.lite.CouchbaseLite.init(CouchbaseLite.java:54)
    at com.couchbase.lite.CouchbaseLite.init(CouchbaseLite.java:42)
    at com.couchbase.lite.CouchbaseLite.init(CouchbaseLite.java:33)
    at de.ihaus.Main.Database.CouchbaseManager.initContext(CouchbaseManager.kt:34)
    at de.ihaus.Main.Dingo$main$1.invoke(Dingo.kt:15)
    at de.ihaus.Main.Dingo$main$1.invoke(Dingo.kt:14)
    at de.ihaus.Main.Login.LoginManager.onLoginSuccess(LoginManager.kt:64)
    at de.ihaus.Main.Login.LoginManager$LoginWorker.run(LoginManager.kt:53)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/ale/Projects/server/CouchbaseLiteTemp/5e3b1711cace9de693b3e1e0bea0f2f8/libLiteCore.dylib: dlopen(/Users/ale/Projects/server/CouchbaseLiteTemp/5e3b1711cace9de693b3e1e0bea0f2f8/libLiteCore.dylib, 0x0001): tried: '/Users/ale/Projects/server/CouchbaseLiteTemp/5e3b1711cace9de693b3e1e0bea0f2f8/libLiteCore.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/libLiteCore.dylib' (no such file)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(ClassLoader.java:2442)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2498)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:2694)
```

I've looked around but CouchbaseLite is supposed to work on an M1.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the problem was the Apple Silicon version of the JDK.
If I run the project with an x86_64 version of the JDK, Rosetta kicks in and it works. Will have to live with the performance hit for now, but at least I'm not blocked anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, CBL-Java doesn't support Native Mac M1 yet.

Answer (score 0):

This will be fixed in cb-lite 3.1.3.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).